# XKB spec says 63 levels max per type. For me it's 8. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: xorg, xkb, setxkbmap

X.org version: 1.21.1.7
Distribution: Kubuntu 23.04

I duplicated the included `EIGHT_LEVEL_ALPHABETIC_LEVEL_FIVE_LOCK` type, inserted an additional level as `Level1`, and shifted all existing levels by +1. The highest level was then `Level9`. Running `setxkbmap` (regardless of specified layout, since no `xkb_symbols` uses this type) yields

> Error loading new keyboard description

Then, if I comment out all references to `Level9` in that type, it works.

Diff here: https://github.com/yue-dongchen/Neo2-QWERTY/commit/66097e14be4aa4012c8f54aaa4ff5739bd559327

---

[Answer to my previous question — *How many levels can XKB accomodate?*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/763554/594763) — which quotes **63 levels** from the XKB specification.

**Edit:** Though I suppose it doesn't really matter, since the layout I'm seeking to modify really only uses the former 7 levels. But it would still be nice to know if I encounter the need in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [*wismill* from xkeyboard-config](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xkeyboard-config/xkeyboard-config/-/issues/425#note_2208023), I discovered that using the numerical identifier `9` as opposed to `Level9`. I don't know why having more than 8 consecutive levels with the identification scheme `Level` + *number* is inadmissible; but at least that resolves the error.

Comment: As a Hunch, the values 0-9 are being treated as `int`s with a length of 1 character.  Counting 0 as a value makes 9.  Anything over 8 creates an overflow error. What happens if you label the levels `Level1` through `Level8` so everything looks the same?

Comment: @eyoung100 I was thinking perhaps. Though `Level0` - `Level8` also doesn't work; so long as levels in that format exceeds 8 it seems.